# how to obtain a list of schemas in intersystems cache?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I'm connecting to a Caché database using the ODBC driver, and I want to do a query to obtain a list of schemas.  In Microsoft SQL Server I can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

How can I do this in Caché?  I'm also using ADO.NET schema collections, but the schemas don't seem to be available there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema %dictionary has the tables you are looking for.  You could select from %dictionary.compiledclass

Comment: That has a SqlSchemaName column you could group on.

Comment: This seems to work: SELECT DISTINCT SqlSchemaName from %dictionary.compiledclass